# Help with bevel

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I´m making a model of an arabian-looking room. When I finished the basic modeling I decided to apply to it a bevel modifier. I selected all the edges in 90 degrees and used the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> but when I saw how it looked I noticed that some of the edges were doing a strange thing (you can see it in the following image).
I have no idea what to do so I hope here I can find the awnser
[image: Bevel problem]

Comment: Have you already un-did it? if so, then post the blend if you can.

Comment: Looks line either inconsistent normals, duplicate geometry, or overlapping vertex. Recalculate normals with `W` > *Remove Doubles* and recalculate normals with `Ctrl`+`N` then redo the bevel.